# Set an entity field value from a generic service

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, repository

I have a generic service that has the basic operations I will need to preform on my entities

a number of my entities have a field `IsEnabled`

I want to be able to set this field from my generic service

my service is defined as :

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T> where T : class
```

Where IService is

```
public interface IService<T>
    {
        IPagedList<T> GetPagedList(
            int page = 1,
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
            params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include
        );

        IEnumerable<T> GetOrderedList(Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null);

        bool Create(T entity);

        bool Update(T entity);

        T FindById(int id);

        bool Delete(T entity);

        void Enable(int id, string state);
    }
```

I want to put the following into my service:

```
public void Enable(int id, string state)
        {
            T entity = FindById(id);

            entity.IsEnabled = (state == "true") ? true : false;

            Update(entity);
        }
```

But VS complains that T does not contain for IsEnabled

how can i assure it that it does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create New Interface IEntity

```
public interface IEntity
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

and your service

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T> where T : class, IEntity
```

And all your Entites must implement it

Comment: This was exactly what I tried, however my Entites are autogenerated (database first) so I dont think I can add an interface to them

Comment: Of course you can, you can create partial class from Entities you will use and implement the interface

Comment: actually, maybe not. now the error when I navigate to the index page is: GenericArguments[0], 'DAL.RebateOption', on 'Website.Services.Service`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.

Comment: Can you debug the Issue and tell me when it throw this Exception ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127899/discussion-between-ahmed-ragheb-and-kevin-bradshaw).